# Creating reusable View in Swift and adding a completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler

I created a sliderView, and added a UIPanGesture and I created a seperate UIView to handle this slider. I want to be able to call this SliderView in different ViewControllers where I need it but when I try to run my code IT crashed.I also would want to pass a completion handler to handle events in the ViewCOntrollers where I would be needing it. I am trying to follow the DRY process by creating one UIView and using it in mutiple screen. Below is my code so far

```
class TripView: UIView {

    var shouldSetupConstraints = true
    var startingFrame: CGRect?

    var sliderView: UIView!
    var sliderImage: UIImageView!

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        swipeFunc()
        sliderView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        sliderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        sliderView.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: screenSize.width / 6)

        self.addSubview(sliderView)

        sliderImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        sliderImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        sliderImage.image = UIImage(named: "icons8-double_right_filled.png")
        sliderImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        sliderImage.autoSetDimension(.width, toSize: screenSize.width / 6)
        sliderImage.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: screenSize.width / 6)

        self.addSubview(sliderImage)


    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        if(shouldSetupConstraints) {

            sliderView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewSafeArea(with: UIEdgeInsets.zero, excludingEdge: .bottom)
            sliderImage.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .left)
            sliderImage.autoPinEdge(.bottom, to: .bottom, of: sliderView, withOffset: 0.0)

            shouldSetupConstraints = false
        }

        super.updateConstraints()
    }
}

extension TripView {

    private func swipeFunc() {

        let swipeGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(acknowledgeSwiped(sender:)))
        sliderImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
        sliderImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        swipeGesture.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    }

    @objc func acknowledgeSwiped(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if let sliderView = sender.view {
            let translation = sender.translation(in: sliderView)
            switch sender.state {
            case .began:
                startingFrame = sliderImage.frame
                fallthrough
            case .changed:
                if let startFrame = startingFrame {

                    var movex = translation.x
                    if movex < -startFrame.origin.x { movex = -startFrame.origin.x }

                    let xMax = sliderView.frame.width - startFrame.origin.x - startFrame.width
                    if movex > xMax {
                        movex = xMax

      // I WANT TO PASS A COMPLETION HANDLER HERE. TO BE ABLE TO HANDLE OTHER     EVENTS IN VIEWCONTROLLERS

                    }

                    var movey = translation.y
                    if movey < -startFrame.origin.y { movey = -startFrame.origin.y }

                    let yMax = sliderView.frame.height - startFrame.origin.y - startFrame.height
                    if movey > yMax {
                        movey = yMax

                    }

                    sliderView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: movex, y: movey)
                }
            default: // .ended and others:
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                    sliderView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                })
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where did it crash?

Comment: here `sliderImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)`

Comment: King, the crash in `sliderImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)` was due to `nil` value for the `sliderImage`. Are you using `TripView(frame:)` method when initializing the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `swipeFunc` which accesses `sliderImage` before `sliderImage` is initialized.

You have to move `swipeFunc()` to the end of your `init` method.

Actually, there is no need to use implicitly unwrapped optionals. You can prevent the crashes by using a non-optional:

```
let sliderView: UIView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
let sliderImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

Since you actually have two initializers, you should probably init everything in both:

```
let sliderView: UIView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
let sliderImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)

    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    commonInit()
}

private func commonInit() {
    sliderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    sliderView.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: screenSize.width / 6)

    self.addSubview(sliderView)

    sliderImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    sliderImage.image = UIImage(named: "icons8-double_right_filled.png")
    sliderImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    sliderImage.autoSetDimension(.width, toSize: screenSize.width / 6)
    sliderImage.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: screenSize.width / 6)

    self.addSubview(sliderImage)

    swipeFunc()
}
```

Regarding a callback, simply declare a property:

```
class TripView: UIView {
    var onChange: (() -> Void)?
}
```

and on every change call:

```
onChange?()
```

In your controller you can then:

```
var tripView: TripView = ...
tripView.onChange = {
  // handle the event
}
```

Comment: @King also you can mention something that he doesn't handle case with initialization with coder.

Comment: @RobertDresler Yeah, I noticed that but I guess he doesn't really support that.

Comment: @RobertDresler I do not quite understand you

Comment: instead of wiping forward, it moves up and returns down

Comment: @king I am sorry but I cannot fix all the issues in your code. Thats why questions have to be very specific on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a completion handler as an internal variable, or pass one in the initialiser.

e.g:

```
class TripView: UIView {
    typealias Callback = () -> ()
    var callback: Callback

    ...
}
```

Then where you want to trigger the callback, simply call:

```
callback()
```

Or you could define a delegate

```
protocol TripViewDelegate {
    func didDoSomething(for view: TripView)
}

class TripView: UIView {
    weak var tripViewDelegate: TripViewDelegate?
    // ...
}
```

And then call

```
tripViewDelegate?.didDoSomething(for: self)
```

Comment: The delegate is not clear. I specified in my question where I would put the action I want to perform in another viewcontroller

Comment: Your viewcontroller should conform to `TripViewDelegate`, then you can assign your viewcontroller as the delegate of the `TripView`. What's not clear about it?